# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Google Vision API android

Tags: java, android, google-vision

```
2020-05-12 22:21:32.300 27492-27492/com.example.smith.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smith.app, PID: 27492
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/vision/face/internal/client/zzc;
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.smith.swipe.SelectProfilePic$3.onClick(SelectProfilePic.java:123)
```

I want to detect if there is a face in the uploaded picture

```
   FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                    .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                    .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
                    .build();
```

When I tried this on a new project, it works flawlessly.

The version I am using on both projects:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Hello, how did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

*Put this in the Manifest `<application>` tag:*

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`